# MultiDimensional ArrayList in kmeans clustering algorithm

Tags: java, eclipse, arraylist, multidimensional-array, k-means

I am trying to implement kmeans algorithm for a certain Music Recommendation System in Java.
I have generated 2 arrays,`playsFinal[]`(the total play-count of an artist by all users in the dataset) and `artFinal[]` (the unique artists in the entire dataset) . The playcount of every `artFinal[i]` is `playsFinal[i]`. For k,I have chosen `kclusters=Math.sqrt(playsFinal.length)/2`.

I have an array `clusters[kclusters][playsFinal.length]`  and the first position `clusters[i][0]` for every `0<i<kclusters` is filled with a certain value,which is basically the initial mean as in kmeans algorithm.

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n && j < kclusters; i += kclusters) {
    clusters[j][0] = weighty[j];//initial means
    System.out.println(clusters[j][0]);
    j++;
}
```

Here,`weight[]` is a certain score given to every artist.
Now,in the following function I am returning the index,ie,which cluster the `plays[i]` should be added to.

```
public static int smallestdistance(double a, double[][] clusters) {
    a = (double) a;
    double smallest = 0;
    double d[] = new double[kclusters];
    for (int i = 0; i < kclusters; i++) {
        d[i] = a - clusters[i][0];

    }
    int index = -1;
    double d1 = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
        if (d[i] < d1) {
            d1 = d[i];
            index = i;
        }
    return index;
}
```

If not obvious,I am finding the minimum distance between `playsFinal[i]` and the initial element in every `clusters[j][0]` and the one that is the smallest,I am returning its index (kfound). Now at the index of the `clusters[kfound][]` I want to add the `playsFinal[i]` but here is where I am stuck. I can't use `.add()` function like in ArrayList. And I guess using an ArrayList would be way better. I have gone through most of the articles on ArrayList but found nothing that could help me. 
 How can I implement this using a multidimensional ArrayList?
Thanks in advance.
My code is put together as follows:

```
int j = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < n && j < kclusters; i += kclusters) {
    clusters[j][0] = weighty[j];//initial means
    System.out.println(clusters[j][0]);
    j++;
}


    double[] weighty = new double[artFinal.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < artFinal.length; i++) {
        weighty[i] = (playsFinal[i] * 10000 / playsFinal.length);

    }
    n = playsFinal.length;

    kclusters = (int) (Math.sqrt(n) / 2);
    double[][] clusters = new double[kclusters][playsFinal.length];

    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n && j < kclusters; i += kclusters) {
        clusters[j][0] = weighty[j];//initial means
        System.out.println(clusters[j][0]);
        j++;
    }

    int kfound;

    for (int i = 0; i < playsFinal.length; i++) {
        kfound = smallestdistance(playsFinal[i], clusters);
        //HERE IS WHERE I AM STUCK. I want to add playsFinal[i] to the corresponding clusters[kfound][]

    }

}


public static int smallestdistance(double a, double[][] clusters) {
    a = (double) a;
    double smallest = 0;
    double d[] = new double[kclusters];
    for (int i = 0; i < kclusters; i++) {
        d[i] = a - clusters[i][0];

    }
    int index = -1;
    double d1 = Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
    for (int i = 0; i < d.length; i++)
        if (d[i] < d1) {
            d1 = d[i];
            index = i;
        }
    return index;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java's "multidimensional arrays" are really just arrays whose elements are themselves (references to) arrays.  The ArrayList equivalent is to create a list containing other lists:

```
List<List<Foo>> l = new ArrayList<>(); //create outer ArrayList
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) //create 10 inner ArrayLists
    l.add(new ArrayList<Foo>());
l.get(5).add(foo1); //add an element to the sixth inner list
l.get(5).set(0, foo2); //set that element to a different value
```

Unlike arrays, the lists are created empty (as any list), rather than with some specified number of slots; if you want to treat them as drop-in replacements for multidimensional arrays, you have to fill them in manually.  This implies your inner lists can have different lengths.  (You can actually get "ragged" multidimensional arrays by only specifying the outer dimension (`int[][] x = new int[10][];`), then manually initializing the slots (`for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) x[i] = new int[i];` for a "triangular" array), but the special syntax for multidimensional array creation strongly predisposes most programmers to thinking in terms of "rectangular" arrays only.)